# Django client.get response has no 'data' attribute

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

TL;DR I can't figure out why a response object has a content attribute but not a data attribute. I'm learning about Django REST Framework using [this tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization) and referencing the [testing approaches here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/).

I'm trying to unit test a REST API response using Django REST Framework. The test is simply trying to assert that the response data length matches the number of objects created in the test, like so:

```py
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

from project.models import SomeObject


class ObjectAPITest(APITestCase):
    def test_get_list_returns_list_of_objects(self):
        SomeObject.objects.create()
        SomeObject.objects.create()

        response = self.client.get(reverse('object-list'))

        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), 2)
```

Right now, for the sake of testing, I have a model that only has a uuid:

```py
import uuid
from django.db import models


class SomeObject(models.Model):
    some_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

And then a simple serializer class:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from project.models import SomeObject


class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeObject
        fields = ['some_id']
```

And of course all of this is wired up in a very simple view:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from project.models import SomeObject
from project.serializers import SomeSerializer


def some_list(request):
    some_objects = SomeObject.objects.all()
    serializer = SomeSerializer(some_objects, many=True)

    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'JsonResponse' object has no attribute 'data'`

But I know that the response has something, because if I add `print(response.content)` I get output I'd expect:

`b'[{"some_id": "241b4a0e-99d4-4239-8034-3afdd77ccb0d"}, {"some_id": "b21d787c-82ec-4e0e-9784-522d84079016"}]'`

I expect `response.data` to return something, because of this specific tip from the Djanto REST Framework testing documentation:

> it's easier to inspect `response.data`

Granted I'm sure I can fix the test by parsing `response.content`, but, since I'm learning, I'm really baffled by why I can't use `response.data` despite it being the recommended approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the testing documentation assumes you're using the Response class from `rest_framework.response` rather than the JsonResponse class from `django.http.response`.

Updating the view to this solved the problem:

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from project.models import SomeObject
from project.serializers import SomeSerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
def some_list(request):
    some_objects = SomeObject.objects.all()
    serializer = SomeSerializer(some_objects, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```